# bats - how can i write errors to a log file instead of the general output + run tests in parralel?

Tags: bash, automation, bats-core

1. I run a lot of [Bats](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) tests in an automated test suite -
   **is there a way to write the failures messages to a separate file??**
   when multiple tests fail it is very unclear because of the massive logs.
   I want the general output to only show "pass/fail" for the tests and the log should contain the errors for each test.
2. Is there a way to run the tests in parallel to save time?

Answer (score 0):

Example code, comments inside:

```
check() {
     #this function emulates your automated test, it has return code, std out, and error out
     echo $1 some error log >&2 
     echo $1 some normal log
     return $1
}

#This two tests are running in parallel in background. 
#Replace 'check 1' with your command to implement.
{ check 1 >> log1 2>>errorlog1 ; 
  RC=$?; 
  [ "$RC" -eq 0 ] \
      && echo Test1 Succeed \
      || echo Test1 Fail
} >>mainlog &

#Replace 'check 0' with your command to implement.
{ check 0 >> log2 2>>errorlog2 ;
  RC=$?;
  [ "$RC" -eq 0 ] \
      && echo Test2 Succeed \
      || echo Test2 Fail
} >> mainlog &
```

This code will produce 5 files on disk.
Output from commands:

```
$ cat log1
1 some normal log

$ cat log2
0 some normal log
```

Errors from commands:

```
$ cat errorlog1
1 some error log

$ cat errorlog2
0 some error log
```

Main Log file with results:

```
$ cat mainlog 
Test1 Fail
Test2 Succeed
```

Comment: how can I implement this? what does the check function do ? in order to run a test, I need to use the @test annotation and your example it has no tests.

Comment: Dear @Nir, test function emulates your automated test, it has return code, std out, and error out. So you need to replace `check 1` and `check 0` with your commands names, which run your tests.

Comment: This looks like generic bash code.  I think he's suggesting that you implement your own test framework instead of dealing with the broken logging in bats.